# Android Studio: Make a Button open Next Activity

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity

I am trying to make an app that includes a MainActivity page and can open another activity: Main2Activity.

Here is my code for the button on the activity_main.xml page

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:onClick="goToMain2Activity"
    android:text="Connect"
    android:textSize="20sp"
```

Here is method to go to the new activity in the MainActivity.java page:

```
public void goToActivity2(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I also declared it in manifest

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name"
android:name="NextActivity"/>
```

I cannot open the app in my emulator, so I am not sure if it is working. I have an error with my Activity Class which isn't allowing it to open, but is my code correct to make the button work? I'm new to coding.

---

**EDIT:**
Here is a copy of my manifest file. I'm not sure how to declare the second activity, if this is not correct.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fonephree.fonephree">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity">
            </meta-data>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The app opens but when I click the button it brings me to the main screen but without the images.

Comment: change the  `android:onClick="goToMain2Activity"` to `android:onClick="goToActivity2"`.
It should be the same name as you have it in your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MainActivity.java, your method should match the name you made in the onClick attribute. So it should look like this instead:

```
public void goToMain2Activity(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Also, declare Main2Activity in the manifest, if not declared.

Comment: You're right. I just didn't include that because I assumed OP had left it out on purpose :)

Comment: I think I declared it in Manifest but I'm not sure what the proper code for that is. Any help?

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the entire manifest file?

Comment: Without being able to run your app, your manifest looks good. Also I saw you accepted my answer, please feel free to upvote!

Answer (score 0):

change this line in your xml code `android:onClick="goToMain2Activity"` to `android:onClick="goToActivity2"`

> Reason: declared a wrong function name in Button.

Answer (score 0):

For your android:onClick="  ” in xml file, the activity name should be the same name as the method called in ur java file. 
Change android:onClick="goToActivity2”